# Regex to find exact match

Tags: python, regex

I have the following scenarios:

```
message: ON
message: "ON"
message: 'ON'
message: "TONC"
message: Los Angeles, ON
message: HOLDS ON FILE
```

I want to match the word ON in the the first three scenarios, and not the others.

I tried with positive/negative lookaheads/behinds to no avail.
ex:

```
\bON\b(?=[\s{0,1}\"{0,1}\'{0,1}]$)
```

Comment: FYI, `{0,1}` is equivalent to `?`.

Comment: Maybe `(?<=:\s)(["']?)\bON\b\1`? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBFiqD/1).

Comment: yeah tried ? as well @0x5453

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to match only `ON`, another option is to use an alternation matching either between a colon followed by a space and a whitespace boundary at the right or between the same type of quotes.

```
(?<=: )ON(?!\S)|(?<=: (['"]))ON(?=\1)
```

- `(?<=: )` Asserting `:` and space on the left
- `ON` Match `ON`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary on the right
- `|` Or
- `(?<=: (['"]))` Assert `:` and space on the left and capture in group 1 `'` or `"`
- `ON` Match `ON`
- `(?=\1)` Assert on the right the same quote that is matched in group 1 using a backreference

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iS7xkv/1)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend munging the string to eliminate the stuff you don't want rather than trying to match directly.  Here I'm just removing non-alpha characters and comparing against the desired result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import re

tests = ['message: ON',
'message: "ON"',
'message: \'ON\'',
'message: "TONC"',
'message: Los Angeles, ON',
'message: HOLDS ON FILE']

for test in tests:
  test = re.sub(r'\W+', '', test)
  print(test)
  print(test == "messageON")
```

Comment: Your question seems very clear; I'm just suggesting that not using `re.match` makes for a much clearer solution here.

Comment: This also matches `%&$&/message!-.,ON°˘˛^°˛˘`

Comment: Sure, it does, but it's MUCH easier to read than a lookbehind, and I addressed all of the failing tests given in the prompt.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
r'''(?<=:\s)(["']?)\bON\b\1'''
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xBFiqD/1). If necessary, add `$` at the end of the pattern to make it match at the end of the string.

**Details**

- `(?<=:\s)`  - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `:` and a whitespace char
- `(["']?)` - Group 1: an optional `"` or `'` char
- `\bON\b` - whole word `ON`
- `\1` - Backreference to Group 1 value, either `"` or `'`.

**NOTE**: If there can be a variable amount of whitespaces between `:` and the `ON` word, you may use [PyPi *regex* module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use `r'''(?<=:\s*)(["']?)\bON\b\1'''` pattern.

Comment: %c5%bcew What do you mean with `Backreference to Group 1`. I didn't get that point.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Do not  use `%c5%bcew`, use `@` + username (`@WiktorStribiżew` in my case). Backreference is the placeholder for some text value that was captured with the corresponding capturing group.

Comment: Your name has special characters :)
Thanks a lot for reply.

Comment: @YasserKhalil Just type `@`, then you will get autosuggestions.

Comment: I didn't get the autosuggestions and I don't know why ..?

Comment: Because in this case, since you are adding comments below **my** post, you do not need the mention, I get notifications in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
message: (['"])?ON(?(1)\1)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ejZowI/1/).

Answer (score 0):

I basically just add `message:` in the regex (`r'^message: ["\']?\bON\b["\']?$'`) :

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from re import search

strings = [
'message: ON',
'message: "ON"',
'message: \'ON\'',
'message: "TONC"',
'message: Los Angeles, ON',
'message: HOLDS ON FILE',
]

for s in strings:
    m = search(r'^message: ["\']?\bON\b["\']?$', s)
    if m is not None:
        print(s)
        print("It's a match !")
```

and it works, here is the output :

```
$ ./regex_to_find_exact_match.py
message: ON
It's a match !
message: "ON"
It's a match !
message: 'ON'
It's a match !
```